# I want to access label and button text from resource file

Tags: .net, maui

I have created one view with some constant text which I want  to set from resources file
I have created .resx file [image]

This is the common file where I have created the button names

```
internal class Common
{

    public const string FILE_ALREADY_EXIST = "FILE_ALREADY_EXIST";
    public const string BTN_ADD_FILE = "BTN_ADD_FILE";
    public const string BTN_ADD_FOLDER = "BTN_ADD_FOLDER";
    public const string BTN_REMOVE_FILE = "BTN_REMOVE_FILE";
    public const string BTN_REMOVE_ALL = "BTN_REMOVE_ALL";
    public const string BTN_HELP = "BTN_HELP";
    public const string BTN_UPGRADE = "BTN_UPGRADE";
    public const string BTN_PREREQUISIES = "BTN_PREREQUISIES";
    public const string BTN_ABOUT_US = "BTN_ABT_US";

}
```

this is my view here I have imported viewmodel

```
 <Button x:Name="BTN_ADD_FILE" ImageSource="add_file.ico" Clicked="Add_File" MaximumHeightRequest="30" BorderColor="Transparent" Text="{}"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="5" TextColor="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="BTN_ADD_FOLDER" ImageSource="add_folder.png" MaximumHeightRequest="30" Clicked="Add_Folder" BorderColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding Model.AddFolder}" Background="Transparent" Padding="5" TextColor="White" />
    <Button x:Name="BTN_REMOVE_BUTTON" ImageSource="remove_file.gif" MaximumHeightRequest="30" Clicked="Remove_File"  BorderColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding Model.RemoveFile}" Background="Transparent" Padding="5" TextColor="White" />
    <Button x:Name="BTN_EXIT" ImageSource="exit.png" MaximumHeightRequest="30" BorderColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding }" Background="Transparent" Padding="5" TextColor="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="BTN_UPGRADE" ImageSource="upgrade.png" MaximumHeightRequest="30" BorderColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding Model.UpgradeTo}" Background="Transparent" Padding="5" TextColor="White"/>
```

I am unable to add reference of .resx file in my view. And I am not able to bind those text in here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text="{x:Static strings:Strings.MyText}"
```

where strings is:

```
xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Strings"
```

and Strings is resx file.

Edit: If you use ResX Manager, you can write the string in your xaml, like Text=Login. Select the string Login > Right click > move to resources. And it will do this magic instead of you.

To clarify this: In the XAML you are trying to bind the Button's Text. Instead of:

```
Text={Binding MyResFile.MyText}
```

You have to write:

```
Text={x:Static namespace:MyResFile.MyText}
```

Comment: I am not being able to add namespace of my .resx file. Don't know why.

Comment: You add this on top of your XAML. Resx file is resx file.